# import typescript modules from java classpath

Tags: javascript, typescript, jar, module, classpath

I want to import a .ts file from a **JAR** file.

I have a file ***widgets.jar*** with a lot of .ts files inside (components like datePicker). 
When another developer want to use datepicker, he writes

```
import { DatePicker } from "./datepicker";
```

but it can't find the module, beacause it searches over physical files.

Any ideas?

I'm choosing **TypeScript** at work because it is **type safe**, and has beautiful **auto-complete** in eclipse (plugin typecs)